# Cannot loop multiple markers from react-native-maps

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

So I have restaurant data which is fetched from the firebase.The data is stored in state as restaurants.The data looks like below.

```
[
    {
        "resName": "KFC",
        "photoUri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/zomato-e0030.appspot.com/o/restaurants%2FDDB3BC53-C787-4D8F-8945-AD56CBEC89C8.jpg?alt=media&token=bb26bff4-9a49-459f-bef0-63cd6f31f428",
        "phNo": "6786785894",
        "userId": "d4cbsBEB4pTMsHHpXT8gkleQMA52",
        "desc": "yhduhw",
        "address": "{\"latitude\":37.78716805152233,\"longitude\":-122.40707527846098}",
        "key": "W2Vt5I8tkBoLsBGJ5WWK"
    },
    {
        "resName": "Thalapakatii",
        "photoUri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/zomato-e0030.appspot.com/o/restaurants%2F4FF27972-6246-48FE-B087-FCAE7E3609B9.jpg?alt=media&token=29c5b686-c509-479a-8528-647701f9dad0",
        "phNo": "9806789890",
        "userId": "d4cbsBEB4pTMsHHpXT8gkleQMA52",
        "desc": "Non Veg Restaurant",
        "address": "{\"latitude\":37.78315900527187,\"longitude\":-122.4291666224599}",
        "key": "ZC2G5Pw6jhRkS6TXrnlo"
    },
    {
        "resName": "Domino’s",
        "photoUri": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/zomato-e0030.appspot.com/o/restaurants%2F54294088-871D-4791-9DE7-B448172A9176.jpg?alt=media&token=f4556591-ede1-4113-831d-a5beb03216c8",
        "phNo": "9879879873",
        "userId": "d4cbsBEB4pTMsHHpXT8gkleQMA52",
        "desc": "Fast Food",
        "address": "{\"latitude\":37.75686216886715,\"longitude\":-122.4325693398714}",
        "key": "w4MsQ3l92hrwzqUBLEAh"
    }
]
```

**When I try to loop the array,the text component is rendered with the names of restaurant on map but the markers are not located on the desired coordinates**

```
 restaurants.length>0&&restaurants.map((res,index)=>{
           let coordinate = JSON.parse(res.address);
          return(
            <>
             <Marker
             key={index}
             pinColor="purple"
             coordinate={coordinate}
            />
            <Text>{res.resName}</Text> 
            </>
          )
         })
```

Comment: Are you able to get proper coordinates by _JSON.parse(res.address);_?

Comment: Yes I got the right coordinates

Comment: I think you have to change _{"latitude":37.75686216886715,"longitude":-122.4325693398714}_ instead of _"{\"latitude\":37.75686216886715,\"longitude\":-122.4325693398714}"_

Comment: As I am parsing the address using JSON.parse() the string will be converted to object key like {latitude:37.75686216886715,longitude:-122.4325693398714}. So that might not be an issue

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the below warning?

> "Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop"

Try changing they key prop to `key={res.resName + index}`.

Comment: there is a `key` property for each `restaurant`, i would propose to use that instead of your answer

Comment: Tried that didn't work